# Simple CSS layout for chat app

Tags: css, layout, html

I want to accomplish a seemingly simple div layout for a basic chat application and tried multiple things already, but none of them worked for this layout.

Here's the idea:
[image: chat layout]

While the red bottom text-input part, and the right userlist part are supposed to be fixed at their location and of fixed size, the center blue content part should fill the remaining space.

The content part and the userlist part are supposed to scroll (green) their content vertically if needed, but there should be no scrollbar for the whole website.

And important: **The whole website should automatically fill the size of the browser window.**

It basically boils down to having columns and rows of "fill remaining space" and "fixed size" mixed, which is easily possible in the environment I usually code in (XAML).

Using features that aren't compatible with old browsers or even Javascript as (very) last resort would be acceptable. **But I don't want to use tables**.

Edit: Here's my current Code. At the moment I only tried to solve this for content and input area. This results in the input area (correctly) always being at the bottom, but the content area still occupying the whole height "behind" the input area. (Setting overflow and height on the messageContainer instead on the outerContainer doesn't help.)

```
<div id="outerContainer">
    <div id="messageContainer">
        <ul id="messageList"></ul>
    </div>

    <div id="inputContainer">
        <input type="text" id="msg"/>
        <button class="btn" id="broadcast">send</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
body
{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#outerContainer
{
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 32px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    overflow:auto;
    height: 100%;
}

#messageContainer
{
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 32px;
    margin-bottom: 72px;
}

#inputContainer
{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    margin-bottom: 32px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 32px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!
Andrej

Comment: I've tried to do similar with my pages and have been unable to find a fill rest of page setting, and 100%-150px, doest work either.  I've had to write a class (using mootools) to achieve what i wanted, (which is similar to delphi panels) where i can add divs and align then, either top, bottom, left, right or client. The issue get even worse when u use margin borders and paddings as the width/height you set the divs too is not the width/height they appear in the browser.  You would think this shoud be easy but it isnt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JFLAp/6)

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="upperPanel">
        <div id="chat">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <span>Name:</span>
                    <span>tessadsda da das asd ad </span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span>Name:</span>
                    <span>tessadsda da das asd ad </span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span>Name:</span>
                    <span>tessadsda da das asd ad </span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="friends">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <span>fRIEND:</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span>fRIEND:</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span>fRIEND:</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span>fRIEND:</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottomPanel">
        <textarea>
        </textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="send" />
    </div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

CSS:

```
html,body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

body{
    position:relative;
}

#wrapper{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    border:1px solid #333;      
}

#upperPanel{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:100px;
}

#chat{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:200px; 
    background:#666;  
    overflow:auto;    
}

#friends{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:200px;
    right:0; 
    background:#999; 
    overflow:auto;   
}

#friends ul{
    text-align:right;
}

#bottomPanel{
    height: 100px;
    background:#EEE;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
}

#bottomPanel textarea{
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    bottom:10px;
    left:10px;
    right:120px; 
    resize: none;
}

#bottomPanel input[type=submit]{
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    bottom:10px;
     right:10px;
    width:100px;
}
```

​

Comment: This looks nearly right, except the important part: The whole website should adapt to the size of the browser window. This (tested locally in FF and Chome) looks like it always has as fixed size.

Comment: So far the closest to the solution. Only thing that is missing now: The right userlist part's width is relative to the total width. Any way to set a fixed width for that part?

Comment: a minor tweak and it's updated! seems like i haven't read all of the specs :)

Comment: Perfect! Huge thanks to you sir. I slowly lost hope that this was possible at all in pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
<style type="text/css">
#left {
    height: 1px;
}
#left div {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

#right {
    width: 100px;
}
#right div {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}

#bottom div {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
}
</style>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="left">
            <div>
                asdfsadf<br />asdf<br /><br /><br />sadf<br />asdfsadf<br />asdfsadf<br />asdfsadf<br />asdfs<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />adf<br />asdfsadf<br />asdfsadf<br />asdfsadf<br />asdfsadf<br />asdfsadf<br />asdfsadf<br />
            </div>
        </td>
        <td id="right">
            <div>
                asdfsadf<br />asdf<br /><br /><br />sadf<br />asdfsadf<br />asdfsadf<br />asdfsadf<br />asdfs<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />adf<br />asdfsadf<br />asdfsadf<br />asdfsadf<br />asdfsadf<br />asdfsadf<br />asdfsadf<br />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="bottom" colspan="2">
            <div></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Edit: Since tables won't do, here's another solution (Javascript).  Using jQuery, the scripting is really simple (without jQuery it's not too difficult either, but jQuery spoils me so this is what I got).  Can't think of any other solutions that don't use Javascript though.

```
<style type="text/css">

#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
}

#left {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    overflow: auto;
}

#right {
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100px;
}

#bottom {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>

<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="left">lefta s d f asdf asdf asd lefta s d f asdf asdf asd lefta s d f asdf asdf asd lefta s d f asdf asdf asd lefta s d f asdf asdf asd lefta s d f asdf asdf asd lefta s d f asdf asdf asd lefta s d f asdf asdf asd</div>

    <div id="right">
        asdfsadf<br />asdf<br /><br /><br />sadf<br />asdfsadf<br />asdfsadf<br />asdfsadf<br />asdfs<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />adf<br />asdfsadf<br />asdfsadf<br />asdfsadf<br />asdfsadf<br />asdfsadf<br />asdfsadf<br />
    </div>

    <div id="bottom">bottom</div>

</div>

<script>
    $(function(){
        var updateLayout = function() {
            $('#left').css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: 0,
                left: 0,
                width: $('#wrapper').innerWidth() - $('#right').outerWidth(),
                height: $('#wrapper').innerHeight() - $('#bottom').outerHeight()
            });
            $('#right').css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: 0,
                left: $('#left').outerWidth(),
                height: $('#wrapper').innerHeight() - $('#bottom').outerHeight()
            });
            $('#bottom').css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: $('#left').outerHeight(),
                left: 0
            });
        };

        updateLayout();

        $(window).resize(function() {
            updateLayout();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, just edited my question regarding this: I don't want to use tables.

Comment: This doesnt seem to adapt to browser window size at all for some reason. I got jQuery 1.7.1 included.

Comment: Easy enough to fix. Just updated it to fill the entire window and adjust whenever the window's resized.

Comment: Adapts to width now, but not to height. The layout however is sadly all wrong. Everything is centered horizontally. Blue content part is top instead of left. Tested on FF and Chrome.

Comment: For the centering, you can simply take out the center tag or add a text-align css attribute. No clue what you mean about the height not adapting or the blue content part being top instead of left.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this and see if you like it. The concept is anchoring to the bottom with positioning. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KwuWZ/2/)

Comment: Also nearly right, except that the messageContainer/content part doesnt seem to resize itself properly horizontally. Also vertically, the content and the username part can disappear to the top for smaller heights.

Comment: Ok... so this is really close if not what you're looking for. I used daxnitro's work as a template. Check it out here: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JFLAp/4/)

Comment: Yes close, but now there's always a margin at bottom that's relative/proportional to the total height. Also the userlist part seems to be relative in width instead of having a fixed size.